# Select previous rows based on condition for current row

Tags: sql, postgresql

The dataset consists of daily (business days) timeseries for different companies. There is also an indicator variable (ind) taking values 1 or 0. If ind is 1 for a given company then I want to build a subsample of the dataset including all entries for this company in a certain time range before the indicator event.

We can think of the following example data:

```
  day              company    ind          
  2012-01-11       A          0            
  2012-01-11       B          0            
  2012-01-11       C          0            
  2012-01-12       A          0            
  2012-01-12       B          0            
  2012-01-12       C          0            
  2012-01-13       A          0            
  2012-01-13       B          1            
  2012-01-13       C          0            
  2012-01-16       A          0            
  2012-01-16       B          0            
  2012-01-16       C          0            
  2012-01-17       A          1            
  2012-01-17       B          0            
  2012-01-17       C          0            
  2012-01-18       A          0            
  2012-01-18       B          1            
  2012-01-18       C          0
```

My goal is a subsample including indicator-event firms A and B for the time range (-2 days to -1 days) before their respective events (It is ensured that in this time range there is no other event for the respective company). This would be my desired result:

```
  day              company    ind         
  2012-01-11       B          0            
  2012-01-12       B          0            
  2012-01-13       A          0            
  2012-01-13       B          0            
  2012-01-16       A          0            
  2012-01-16       B          0            
  2012-01-17       B          0
```

The following code works, if there is only one indicator event for only one company in the dataset:

```
    CREATE TABLE temp AS
    SELECT Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY day) AS rowid, *
    FROM   mytable

    CREATE TABLE window AS SELECT * 
                        FROM temp t1
                        WHERE company IN (
                                        SELECT company
                                        FROM temp t2
                                        WHERE t2.ind = 1)
                        AND rowid BETWEEN((SELECT rowid FROM temp where ind = 1) - 2)  
                                  AND ((SELECT rowid FROM temp where ind = 1) -1)
```

But I am really struggling to extent it to the case with more than one event company and maybe several events per company as in the example dataset.

Do you have any ideas how this problem can be solved?

Comment: Seems easiest to do this with the `LEAD()` function, which allows you to evaluate data from rows 'ahead' of your current row.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Where in my code would it be appropriate to use the LEAD() function? @GoatCO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're partitioning by company in your attempt I'm assuming that you don't really want the following line in your results:

```
2012-01-13       B          0
```

If that's the case, you can use `LEAD()` to look ahead 1 or 2 rows to see if the `ind` flag is populated:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT * ,LEAD(ind) OVER(PARTITION BY company ORDER BY day) AS Lead1
                      ,LEAD(ind,2) OVER(PARTITION BY company ORDER BY day) AS Lead2
             FROM Table1)
SELECT Day,Company,Ind
FROM cte
WHERE Lead1 = 1 
  OR  Lead2 = 1
ORDER BY day,company
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/78f45/16/0)

Update:  Given a larger range, this approach is better as you can specify how many rows ahead you want to look (demo updated to include both):

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *
                  , MAX(ind) OVER(PARTITION BY company ORDER BY day ROWS BETWEEN 1 following AND 2 following) Lead1
             FROM Table1)
SELECT Day,Company,Ind
FROM cte
WHERE Lead1 = 1 
ORDER BY day,company
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working perfectly!! Do you know a trick how to avoid typing LEAD(ind,1), LEAD(ind,2),..., LEAD(ind,30)? The window I actually need is much larger than 2 days, but I didn't want to post such a long time series. @GoatCO

Comment: @user3319629 See update, you can create a window on the `MAX()` function to see if there's any ind flag populated in the next `n` rows.  Just update `2 following` to be `30 following` or whatever.

Comment: That is great! Thanks again, now it's even better for my purpose! @GoatCO